# How to add static parametr to selected GET Retrofit calls?

Tags: android, parameters, retrofit

I have use a lot of Retrofit calls (GET,PUT,DETELE,etc.). I know, I can do it for all calls, but I must set it only to GET calls. But now I have to add one static parametr to all GET calls, what is best way to do it?

My call examples:

```
@GET("user")
Call<User> getUser(@Header("Authorization") String authorization)

@GET("group/{id}/users")
Call<List<User>> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId, @Query("sort") String sort);
```

I need for all GETs to add parametr: 
**&something=true**

I tried to add is this way, but this require to fix all calls to interface:

```
public interface ApiService {

    String getParameterVariable = "something"
    boolean getParameterValue = true

    @GET("user")
    Call<User> getUser(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                       @Query(getParameterVariable) Boolean getParameterValue)

}
```

Answer (score 4):

**This answer assume that you are using `OkHttp` together with `Retrofit`.**

You have to add an interceptor to your `OkHttpClient` instance that filters all `GET` requests and apply a query parameter.
You can do it in this way:

```
// Add a new Interceptor to the OkHttpClient instance.
okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        // Check the method first.
        if (request.method().equals("GET")) {
            HttpUrl url = request.url()
                    .newBuilder()
                    // Add the query parameter for all GET requests.
                    .addQueryParameter("something", "true")
                    .build();

            request = request.newBuilder()
                    .url(url)
                    .build();
        }
        // Proceed with chaining requests.
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
});
```